# Upload local file and update spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Good morning,
because a privacy policy I am no longer able to upload/update my Google Drive spreadsheets by python. Authentification is not working. My new solution is to upload the locale file by Google Scripts for example wieht WebApps. I know how to upload a simple locale file on Google Drive:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
    .setTitle('Name To Appear in Browser Tab')

}

function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob = theForm.picToLoad;

  Logger.log("fileBlob Name: " + fileBlob.getName())
  Logger.log("fileBlob type: " + fileBlob.getContentType())
  Logger.log('fileBlob: ' + fileBlob);

  var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById("my folder");
    fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob);

  return true;
}
```

My question is how to set a specific locale folder (at the moment I am only able to choose file manually) and how can I update an existing spreadsheet on Google Drive by this script. At the moment I get for every upload a new file ...

Comment: You may want to use [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) instead of Drive API to update your spreadsheet

Comment: If you are using Google Apps Script, use the [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).